# Grant a user sudo powers to start/stop/etc a systemd service w/o sudo password

Tags: systemd, sudo

I have one non-root user, and I would like to give them sudo permission to start & stop (etc.) a systemd service file without needing a password.

I tried to just make the following file in `/etc/sudoers.d/servicename` *(where `[username]` and `[servicename]` are the actual names)*:

```
[username] ALL=(root) NOPASSWORD: systemctl start [servicename]
[username] ALL=(root) NOPASSWORD: systemctl stop [servicename]
[username] ALL=(root) NOPASSWORD: systemctl restart [servicename]
```

*(repeated for lots of system commands, like `reload`/`try-restart`/`enable`/…)*

But `visudo` told me that was a syntax error. How can I fix that?

I want to put in scripts (which are being run as this non-root user) `sudo systemctl stop [servicename]`.

Ubuntu Linux 18.04, systemd from ubuntu (which for this is v245). I also want this to work on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can implement what you want by using the following:

```
Cmnd_Alias USER_SERVICES = /usr/bin/systemctl start [servicename], /usr/bin/systemctl stop [servicename], /usr/bin/systemctl restart [servicename]

[username] ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:USER_SERVICES
```

You can add more commands to USER_SERVICES by placing a comma (,) between them. Always use the full path for the command.

Comment: works like a charm

Comment: sorry, what is this? where do I put this..?

Comment: You can put the instructions in `/etc/sudoers` file or in a `/etc/sudoers.d/filename` where filename can be any name. To create a valid configuration use the visudo tool to edit the sudoers file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add user/group in `sudoers` file with required privileges/commands. Execute below command to open `sudoers` file (***root privileges or sudo access required to execute this command***)

```
> sudo visudo
```

Then add below lines at the end and save file (**To save your changes and exit vim, press `ESC` and then type `:wq` --> press `enter`**)

```
%[group] ALL=([username]) NOPASSWD: ALL

%[group] ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start [servicename],/bin/systemctl stop [servicename],/bin/systemctl restart [servicename]
```